# What is the C# equivalent of Java's Locale.ROOT and Locale.getDefault()?

Tags: java, c#

When converting Java to C#, what is the proper way to translate Locale to CultureInfo?

I know in C# we have `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` for the current thread's culture, and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for cases where we want to provide consistency for the sake of writing to files. But what do the Java Locale.ROOT and Locale.getDefault() mean, and how do they generally map to the `CultureInfo` options in C#?

Comment: Well, unless you change the current culture of your threads, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` will be the system's default culture.

Comment: *"what do the Java [`Locale.ROOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT) and [`Locale.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--) mean?"* Which part of the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) describing them is unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, thanks to Andreas, I can surmize from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
Locale.ROOT (Java) == CultureInfo.InvariantCulture (C#)
```

And

```
Locale.getDefault() (Java) == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture (C#)
```

I just wish that document was easier to find! I had Googled things like `java locale.root equivalent c#` and `java locale.getdefault equivalent c#` with no useful results.