# Is C#'s CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and Java's Locale.ROOT equal?

Tags: java, c#, locale

Is `C#`'s `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and `Java`'s `Locale.ROOT` equal?

Comment: They seem to serve the same purpose.

Comment: Related question, similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108804/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-javas-locale-root-and-locale-getdefault

Answer (score 1):

actually they are not equal but almost they serve the same propose.